# Pressure dependent rate coefficient

Tags: pressure, ozone

I am trying to study how the pressure will affect the formation of ozone at around 5 bar. So, I am looking for a simple relation between the reaction rate coefficient and the pressure to use it in my simulation. Is there any suggestion?

Comment: Why would there be a relation in the first place?

Comment: If you already have the model of reaction mechanism and kinetics, you just plug in the pressure into the initial conditions.

Comment: @IvanNeretin In some papers, it seems to depend on the pressure. see for example  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindemann_mechanism or https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0010218084901093

Comment: @Poutnik I do not know how the pressure affects the reaction in the first place. So, I need an equation that relates the pressure with the rate coefficient.

Comment: Well, if you have a set of reactions and kinetics, you already know how pressure affects them. If you do not have them, then you do not know. How about to add to your question the reaction and kinetic model you are analyzing ? Then other may put their hand on it and help you analyze the pressure effects.